# Eclipse Indigo STS + JBoss Tools

Tags: eclipse, spring, jboss-tools

I cannot install JBoss Tools on my Indigo. I open supermarket and install current version for my eclipse or I try to open Install new software from link (http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/indigo/) but i still has got the same error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: JBoss Central Community 1.0.1.v20120715-0355-H112-Final (org.jboss.tools.community.central.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.v20120715-0355-H112-Final)
  Software currently installed: Spring IDE AOP Extension (optional) 3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.aop.feature.feature.group 3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Mylyn Commons UI 3.8.1.v20120725-0100 (org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 3.8.1.v20120725-0100)
    Mylyn Commons UI 3.6.1.v20110720-0100 (org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 3.6.1.v20110720-0100)
    Mylyn Commons UI 3.8.2.v20120916-1200 (org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 3.8.2.v20120916-1200)
    Mylyn Commons UI 3.8.0.v20120612-0600 (org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 3.8.0.v20120612-0600)
    Mylyn Commons UI 3.6.0.v20110608-1400 (org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 3.6.0.v20110608-1400)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JBoss Central 1.0.1.v20120715-0355-H112-Final (org.jboss.tools.central 1.0.1.v20120715-0355-H112-Final)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui [3.6.0,3.8.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JBoss Central 1.0.1.v20120715-0355-H112-Final (org.jboss.tools.central.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.v20120715-0355-H112-Final)
    To: org.jboss.tools.central [1.0.1.v20120715-0355-H112-Final]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JBoss Central Community 1.0.1.v20120715-0355-H112-Final (org.jboss.tools.community.central.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.v20120715-0355-H112-Final)
    To: org.jboss.tools.central.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.qualifier
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring IDE AOP Extension (optional) 3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.aop.feature.feature.group 3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE)
    To: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring IDE Configuration Graphical Editing 3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.config.graph 3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui [3.7.0,4.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring IDE Core (required) 3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE)
    To: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.config.graph [3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE]
```

Comment: I try to fix this problem all night;/ finally I replace my Eclipse version and upgrade to Juno. On Eclipse Juno everything was installed without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse Indigo.

I installed the STS plugin first.

Then when I attempted to install the Jboss tools plugin. I received the same error.

I unchecked JBoss Central Community, and JBoss Tools Common - Mylyn.  Pressed Next (no errors this time).

After doing so you have to restart the IDE.  You should now have both plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Please TRY 
Eclipse 3.7.2 Platform Runtime Binary INDIGO SR2 IDE for JAVA EE DEVELOPERS

And then go for JBOSS tool.

Follow this link
http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/installation/update_3_3